# how to create captcha in codeigniter 2.1.0

Tags: codeigniter, captcha, helper

How to create captcha in codeigniter 2.1.0 load helper codeigniter ?
when i have model m_captcha :

```
    function __construct()
{
            parent::__construct();
}

    function setCaptcha()
    {
            $this->load->helper('captcha');
            $vals = array(
                'img_path'          => './asset/captcha',
                'img_url'           => base_url().'/asset/captcha',
                'expiration'        => 3600,// one hour
                'font_path'     => './system/fonts/georgia.ttf',
                'img_width'     => '140',
                'img_height'        => 30,
                'word'          => random_string('numeric', 6),
                );

            $cap = create_captcha($vals);
            if ($cap)
            {
                    $capdb = array(
                        'captcha_id'        => '',
                        'captcha_time'      => $cap['time'],
                        'ip_address'        => $this->CI->input->ip_address(),
                        'word'              => $cap['word']
                    );
                    $query = $this->db->insert_string('captcha', $capdb);
                    $this->db->query($query);
            }else {
                            return "Captcha not work" ;
                     }

                return $cap['image'] ;
}
```

and i have controller c_login :

```
   function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('m_captcha');
}   

    public function index()
    {
          $this->load->helper('captcha');
          $data = $this->m_captcha->setCaptcha();                            
          $this->load->view('login/v_form',$data);                        
    }
```

and i have view :

```
<?php echo form_open('c_login'); ?>
 <?php echo  $cap['image']; ?>
<?php echo form_error('captcha');?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

why the captcha cannot show in view ?
position folder and image captcha in sms/asset/captcha .
sms is folder root Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php echo  $cap['image']; ?>` is the problem.

Lets check the flow once again, you are returning the `$cap['image']` from model.

And after that, you accepted that in `$data` in controller.

It must be something `$data['capcha']` so that you can access it using `$capcha` in view.

Very Simple.

Comment: i change  $data = $this->m_captcha->setCaptcha();
with 
$data['captcha'] = $this->m_captcha->setCaptcha();
and 
view <?php echo  $cap['image']; ?> 
with 
<?php echo $captcha['image']; ?> 

but the result is :
C , only letter C , no images captcha and other letter.

Comment: again you are mistaking, look above description very carefully. You are already returning `'image'` from model so in view you can not access as the `$captcha['image']`, it must be just `$captcha`.

Comment: [check here] (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html), its very simple.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much kuku, problem solved, and because i'm forget to change permission 777 in folder captcha.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use reCaptcha instead? http://codeigniter.com/wiki/ReCAPTCHA
It's easy to implement!